# Question about computing percentage changes in an RPG skill

Tags: percentages

I'm a little confused about percentages.

Basically, in the latest patch notes for this RPG I've been playing, the numbers for a skill have changed as follows:

```
57.4 damage per second => 45.92 damage per 0.8 seconds
```

In a reddit thread, this was computed as a $25\%$ damage decrease and a $25\%$ trigger frequency increase:

```
57.4 / 45.92 = 1.25
1 / 0.8 = 1.25
```

Is this correct?  Shouldn't it be a $20\%$ damage decrease with a $25\%$ trigger frequency increase?

```
57.4 damage * 8 triggers over 8 seconds
45.92 damage * 10 triggers over 8 seconds

57.4 -> 45.92 is a 20% decrease
8 -> 10 is a 25% increase
```

Comment: You're right. Percentages are always calculated relative to the original value, not the new value. Both the numerator (damage) and denominator (period length) were decreased by 20%, so the rate stays the same. The frequency, which is the reciprocal of period did increase by 25%, but that's ok because $1.25=1/0.8$.